# Размер данных dataGridView

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, ado.net

Как можно узнать объем (в килобайтах, байтах) данных, хранящихся в `dataGridView(DataTable)`?

Comment: Вам нужен реальный размер данных в памяти (есть определённый дополнительный расход памяти на отображение и прочее), или суммарный размер данных, которые данные займут в таблице (но у таблицы свои дополнительные расходы)?

Comment: Реальный размер, только данных

Comment: Ну, для каждого из типов элемента вам нужна своя процедура подсчёта. `byte`, `char`, `int` и тому подобное занимают фиксированный размер. `string` занимает по идее размер равный своей длине на размер `char`'а. Если у вас есть более сложные структуры, размер их считается рекурсивно по размерам составляющих их данных.

Comment: можно хотя бы название класса, для большого понимая выше написанного

Comment: @Serg29: Не вполне понимаю, о каком классе вы говорите?

Comment: я не совсем понял описанной методики, есть универсальный метод подсчета или суммировать размер строк единственных выход

Comment: Суммировать размер строк :-( Или `int`'ов. Или что у вас тип колонки. Есть как бы автоматическое решение, основанное на `Marshal.SizeOf`, но у него свои проблемы (строки, bool, всякое такое), так что вручную будет проще.

Comment: Очевидно в вопросе идет речь о DataGridView из WinForms и DataTable из Ado.NET. Если так вам стоит скорректировать вопрос. Хотя `DataGridView` и занимает место в памяти, строго говоря никаких данных оно не хранит, оно используется для _отображения_ данных. В стандартном сценарии `DataGridView` привязывается к `DataTable` через `BindingSource`. Данные хранятся в `DataTable` и вероятно именно размер `DataTable` вы хотите знать. Если так, скорректируйте вопрос, а то формулировка `dataGridView(DataTable)` добавляет двусмысленности.

Comment: Кроме того, напишите вкратце _зачем_ вам надо знать размер этих данных, потому что это может влиять на варианты решения вашей задачи. Вы хотите посмотреть это размер разово в целях отладки или вам надо вычислять его в своей программе каждый раз во время ее работы?

Answer (score 2):

Небольшое уточнение - данные хранятся в *DataTable*, а *DataGridView* лишь используется для их отображения.

Чтобы посмотреть сколько данных хранится в *DataTable*, запустите ваше приложение и сделайте дамп его памяти с помощью диспетчера задач, вот так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если вы запуститие ваше приложение из Visual Studio, оно будет отображаться в диспетчере задач, как дочерний процесс процесса Visual Studio, и для него в контекстном меню не будет пункта "Create dump file". Поэтому не запускайте приложение из Visual Studio, найдите на диске exe-файл и запустите его сами.

Диспетчер задач сохранит дамп памяти в папку Temp и покажет вам путь к файлу. Далее вам надо открыть полученный дамп-файл в Visual Studio как любой другой файл, через команду меню `File -> Open -> File`.

В окне с открым дампом кликайте кнопку *Debug Managed Memory*:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В итоге вы увидете то, что вам требуется - список объектов в памяти, с указанием их размера, отсортированный по убыванию. В списке вы сможете найти вашу `DataTable`, увидеть сколько она занимает памяти, и более детально исследовать между какими, вложенными в DataTable объектами, делится эта память

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]